# How to change boot order from within Windows OS?

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I'm in a situation that I don't know how to solve.

I have a machine in another country where I only access remotely, and eventually in rare cases someone can go there to help me. In this case I wanted to avoid as much as I had to ask someone to go there.

My question is, I have in this machine 2 HDDs connected. One with Windows 7 and another with Windows 10. Today, while I was working on Windows 10, I needed to reboot the machine and it started up from Windows 7 HDD, and continuing to reboot it always does the same.

Is there any way I can change this order through Windows without having to access the BIOS locally?

Comment: Answer of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1050238/how-do-edit-the-contents-of-my-bios-boot-list) question may help.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. They did not solve my question directly, but through them I learned that I have to configure BIOS settings (intel vPro) so that the next time I can solve an issue like this.